# Non-negative Matrix Factorization - Basic Question: Cluster Assignment

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dimensionality-reduction, unsupervised-learning, non-negative-matrix-factorization

Given the  result $V_{m\times n} \approx W_{m\times k} \cdot H_{k\times n}$, where columns of $V$ are data points and $m$ is data dimension, what is the function by which you assign the data points to the $k$ classes?

Is the usual method to use the normalized columns of $W$ as centroids?

It seems like that would be problematic since even a normalized version of $W$ is not unique. For example if $R$ is a rotation matrix $WR\cdot R^{-1}H = W \cdot H$ where $WR$ is still normalized.